# Using intel_iommu=on keeps system from booting

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to build a dual desktop - Ubuntu as base OS and a Windows 10 VM for games and other Windows lockin crap.

The motherboard I'm using is the (awesome on paper) ASRock C236M WS, I put a Xeon 1245-E3v5 into it plus 32GB ECC RAM.

But I can't seem to enable IOMMU, which is 100% essential.  Adding "intel_iommu=on" to /etc/default/grub => GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT argument makes the system not boot at all (columns of lines appear onscreen).  Adding  the "intremap=no_x2apic_optout" doesn't seem to help, either way the system won't boot when the iommu flag is set.

I've tried with and without the x2apic flag.  And yes, I am running `sudo update-grub` after each  change to the grub config file.

Is this board just a piece of crap or does anyone have ideas?

Comment: VT-d Compatible ASRock Motherboards  Socket 1155, 2011, 1150: ASRock H77 Pro4-M     ASRock Z68 Extreme4 Gen3    ASRock Z68 Professional Gen3     ASRock Z77 Pro3     ASRock Z77 Pro4     ASRock Z77 Extreme4     ASRock Z77 Extreme6     ASRock Z77 Professional     ASRock X79 Extreme9 socket 2011 - CPUs known to work with a motherboard from below list and a proper BIOS: Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1245 v5
(

Comment: @kyodake Not sure where you got this list from, but those all look like desktop chipsets, and I need ECC memory and a uATX form factor.  The Xeon E3-1245 v5 is the exact CPU I'm using.  Also, the BIOS on the C236M WS has a VT-d option which is enabled, which leads me to believe it should be able to do IOMMU.

Answer (score 0):

I never got to the bottom of it exactly, but I did confirm that the Asrock C236M WS motherboard will not boot with intel_iommu=on and a 4.3 (Debian backports) or 4.4 (Ubuntu 16.04) kernel.

It works ok with a Debian Jessie 3.16 kernel, but I didn't want to be tied to the old kernel, so I went with a different motherboard.